# Catch errors from validation when saving product or category ($product->validate() or $category->validate())

Tags: magento2, programmatically, validation

I would like to validate the data before saving a product programatically because `->save()` saves a product even if it doesn't have an sku.

If I do `->validate()` I get the expected error:

```
[Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Exception]  
  The value of attribute "sku" must be set
```

But I would like to catch that error and log it somewhere and let the script continue on another product.

This doesn't work:

```
try{
    $product->validate();
} catch(Exception $e){
}
```

If I look at the validate method it doesn't supply much info about where can I catch the error (except for that @todo):

```
\module-catalog\model\Product.php
    /**
         * Validate Product Data
         *
         * @todo implement full validation process with errors returning which are ignoring now
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function validate()
        {
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_validate_before', $this->_getEventData());
            $result = $this->_getResource()->validate($this);
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_validate_after', $this->_getEventData());
            return $result;
        }
```

I imagine it is quite a common task. Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check like this:

```
$errors = $product->validate();
//validate returns true if everything is ok and an array with the errors otherwise
if (is_array($errors)) { 
    //log your errors
} else {
    //proceed to save
}
```

The errors array should look like this:

```
array(
     'attribute_code1_here' => 'Error message 1 here',
     'attribute_code2_here' => 'Error message 2 here',
     ....
)
```

There is a catch also.
If the product is not assigned to an attribute set, you will get only this error

```
array('attribute_set' => 'Invalid attribute set entity type');
```

all the other errors will not be shown for that product.

For the categories it works the same without the restriction on the attribute set because there is only one attribute set for the categories.

**[EDIT]**
before calling `$product->validate()` call this:

```
$product->setCollectExceptionMessages(true);
```

This will collect all the validation error messages inside an array and it will not throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one. But the script still dies here:  `$errors = $product->validate(); `  with `[Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Exception] The value of attribute name must be set ` and executing nothing afterwards. Was this working in magento1?

Comment: hmm...let me check again. Maybe there are some other things that are checked during validation

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga. See my edit. Maybe it works this time.

Comment: Wonderful. thanks. now it is working as expected.